# Trim string with trim.End

Tags: c#, xml, string, char, trim

I want to trim a String with more than 1 character.
The String:

```
<incident_response>
<msg_id>50889_360</msg_id>
<inquiry_id>INC000000087930</inquiry_id>
<response_dt>02.26.2013 14:49:12</response_dt>
<status>0</status>
<error></error>
</incident_response>
```

Yes, I know, it is a XML File.

```
string responseXML;
string inc_number = 
responseXML.Trim().Trim('<inquiry_id>').TrimEnd('</inquiry_id>');
```

I got a CS1012 error, because the are more than one char. I need the whole **inquiry_id (INC000000087930)** without any other chars. Is there another option to get the number? I can't use the xmlready or something like this, because I get the XML as a string from an API module.

Comment: You should use an XML parser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having the XML as a string doesn't prevent you from using any of the XML APIs. The easiest to use is the XLinq API. It should be available in .NET 3.5, too.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string inquiryId = (string)doc.Root.Element("inquiry_id");
```

Comment: Actually removing the string directly should be faster because of the fact that XDocument parses the xml first. Or i'm wrong?

Comment: @FelixK.: You could be right, but why care? This most likely isn't a performance bottleneck and the code using a XML parser is more robust and expressive.

Comment: You are right. But when you are just writing "This is wrong, use this." the op doesn't know how to use the methods correctly. :-)

Comment: okay, I try it. He couldnt find the namespace for xdocument. I try to use the namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.90).aspx), but also he cant find the library linq.

Comment: @ManuelFischer: Did you add a reference to System.Xml.Linq to your project?

Comment: dont think so, I try to implement it. Its possible in vs05?

Comment: @ManuelFischer: It should be possible, because you are using .NET 3.5 IIRC.

Comment: cant find the library linq. Its right so search in the objektbrowser?

Comment: @ManuelFischer. No, that's not correct. You have to do it like so: Right-click on your project -> Add Reference -> .NET -> Select "System.Xml.Linq"

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to work with strings something like this might work

```
 responseXML.Substring(responseXML.IndexOf("<inquiry_id>"), responseXML.IndexOf("</inquiry_id>"))
```

But using an XML API in your case is a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the inquiry _id you could use an Regular Expressions.

```
string your_xml = @"<incident_response>
<msg_id>50889_360</msg_id>
<inquiry_id>INC000000087930</inquiry_id>
<response_dt>02.26.2013 14:49:12</response_dt>
<status>0</status>
<error></error>
</incident_response>";


Regex re = new Regex(@"<inquiry_id>(?'inquiry_id'.*?)</inquiry_id>");
MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(your_xml);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Groups["inquiry_id"].Value);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Maybe you cannot parse **every** XML, but the snippet he gave us, can be parsed without problems with help of Regex. So why shouldn't he use it?

Comment: Because there are tools for parsing XML. Why not use them instead?

Comment: BTW: Downvote isn't from me. I don't think it deserves one, because your solution still works and is reasonable simple.

Answer (score -1):

C# supports stringVariable.Replace(string, string), which will replace all occurrences of the first string with the second.

```
string responseXML;
string inc_number = 
    responseXML.Replace("<inquiry_id>", string.Empty).Replace("</inquiry_id>", string.Empty);
```

But you will still need to deal with the rest of the XML. An XML parser is better-suited to your needs I think.

Comment: This doesn't return the expected result - which is `INC000000087930`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
string str = "ggAAAff";
string prefix = "gg";
string suffix = "ff";
if (str.EndsWith(suffix)) str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - suffix.Length);
if (str.StartsWith(prefix)) str = str.Substring(prefix.Length);
```